# Autohotkey - remember length scrolled

Tags: browser, autohotkey

I want to know if there is any way to make a script like this:

On the page, press "some button" - to go to the top of the page.
Press it again - to return to previous position.

I know that Autohotkey can somehow remember scrolled distance, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it’s not elegant, but what I have done in the past to achieve your purpose is the keystroke 1st checks that it’s Not at top of document; if true, leave a unique string (eg: vq); if false, Find & delete string.